# Get Path of Package File

Tags: svn, version-control, enterprise-architect

I use `Enterprise Architect` with version control.

I would like to retrieve the XML file path which is related to the package .
Using the API `package.XMLPath` property returns only the file name, but not the full path.

**For example:** if a package is configured to `C:\\svnFolder\packageName.xml` if I perform `package.XMLPath` I get only `packageName.xml`.

Comment: The package.XMLPath is working fine in my EA, giving output such as `technical\data\TableList.xml`. Have you check your version control settings? You can also do quick check using Ctrl + Alt + P on the package (Package Control --> Configure)

Comment: @David, Thanks. I search hoe to get this programmatically. See updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full path of version controlled packages, you need to do the following:

1. Get the VCCFG of the package

   - Get the the flags of the package using `package.Flags`. A sample output will be `"Recurse=0;VCCFG=Test_EA_Testing;CheckedOutTo=stepanus.kurniawan;"`
   - Parse the flags string to get only the VCCFG. In the above sample, you shall get only  `"Test_EA_Testing"`. **Hint:** Use string split
2. Get the path of the version control

   - Open `%AppData%/Roaming/Sparx Systems/EA/paths.txt`. This limits you to **use JScript or VBScript only**, because JavaScript does not have ActiveX ability to read file.
   - Iterate through each line of the file
   - When iterating, find VCCFG matching from step 1 with the `id=`
   - Store the value of `path=`
   - For example, the line consist of `%PATH%;type=Version Control;id=Test_EA_Testing;path=H:\Documents_temp\Test_EA_WorkingCopy;`, then you need to get `H:\Documents_temp\Test_EA_WorkingCopy`
3. Combine the result from step 2 with `'\'` and `package.XMLPath`.